# PrestaShop/Smarty change {$image. based on filter $q=Color-Black -- please

Tags: php, templates, prestashop, smarty

I am kind of new on PrestaShop and I would like to learn more about Smarty templates and .tpl files.

I have a problem with changing `{$image.bySize.home_default.url}` inside *products.tpl*

I'll try to explain my situation:

.

---

.

**Category filter**

[ps_facetedsearch > Filters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImoEX.png)

**Product from category**

[themes\footwear\templates\catalog_partials\miniatures\product.tpl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tdng.png)

```css
/*
  where can I create/modify/add 
  {$image.bySize.home_default.url}
*/
```

```html
<!--
themes\footwear\templates\catalog\_partials\miniatures\product.tpl
-->

<div class="thumbnail-wrapper">
        {block name='product_thumbnail'}
          <a href="{$product.url}" class="thumbnail product-thumbnail">
            {foreach name="thumbnails" from=$product.images item=image}
              
              {if $smarty.foreach.thumbnails.iteration == 2}
                <img
                  class="thumbnail-alternate"
                  src="{$image.bySize.home_default.url}"  <!-- ?? -->
                  alt="{$image.legend}"
                >
              {/if}
              
            {/foreach}
            {if $product.cover}
            <img
              class="thumbnail-img"
              src="{$product.cover.bySize.home_default.url}"
              alt="{$product.cover.legend}"
              data-full-size-image-url = "{$product.cover.large.url}"
              itemprop="image"
            >
            {else}
            <img
                class="thumbnail-img"
                src="{$urls.no_picture_image.bySize.home_default.url}"
              >
            {/if}
          </a>
        {/block}
          {block name='product_flags'}
          <ul class="product-flags">
            {if $product.has_discount}
                {if $product.discount_type === 'percentage'}
                  <li class="discount-percentage">{$product.discount_percentage}</li>
                {elseif $product.discount_type === 'amount'}
                  <li class="discount-percentage">{$product.discount_amount_to_display}</li>
                {/if}
            {/if}
            {foreach from=$product.flags item=flag}
              <li class="{$flag.type}">{$flag.label}</li>
            {/foreach}
          </ul>
          {/block}
        </div>
```

---

**What I'd like to change**

When I put a filter (Black/White) I still see my default color cloth and It's very messy.
When I filter all white cloths, I would like to see all white cloths and not blue, red, yellow, green that also is available in black or white.

I tought that I could change the {$image.bySize.home_default.url} in the product.tpl when the url changed:

*domain.com/3-clothes* **?q=Color-White**

I can't find any .php file that is related to {$image.bySize.home_default.url} and I can't write `<?php ?>` inside .tpl files.

```
{$image.bySize.home_default.url} = /1087-home_default/bari.jpg (black)
    
if ($_GET['q']=Color-white
/1151-home_default/bari.jpg (white)
```

**Can someone help me?**
or explain me how this Smarty templates works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also want to share that the. Tpl files are Smarty Template Engine.  It's a a kind of  HTML+PHP mixture.

The php $_GET can be used in Smarty with {$smarty.get.key}

I hope it helped you a bit.